# How to use onDeleteEntry?

Tags: events, hook

I currently have a plugin which needs to do things on save and delete entry events. My save entry code is all working perfectly but the [onDeleteEntry](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onDeleteEntry) code doesn't ever fire when I delete an entry.

I have tried using the event both ways mentioned in the documentation

```
craft()->entries->onDeleteEntry = function(Event $event) {
$entry = $event->params['entry'];
//etc etc
};
```

and

```
craft()->on('entries.deleteEntry', function(Event $event) {
$entry = $event->params['entry'];
//etc etc
});
```

both of these are inside the init function.

Does anyone know if there is a particular way this event needs to be used that differs from the [onSaveEntry](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onSaveEntry) event, which works fine?

Here's a link to the events reference https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#events

Comment: Were you testing this from the Entry index page by chance?

Comment: @BradBell I'm also having this same issue, when viewing the list of entries, ticking them and deleting them that way. Is there any way around this? (Using latest build of Craft)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently found that if your deleting an entry on the entries list, you need to use the onBeforePerformAction event. Then break this down, like J Thomas states on this -

[Get the type of action and the elements(s) that an action is being performed on when listening to elements.onPerformAction?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/get-the-type-of-action-and-the-elementss-that-an-action-is-being-performed-on)